# how to load array elements in MMX or SSE registers to do sum operation on them

Tags: c++, simd, mmx

I have the code bellow.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <sstream>
    #include <string>
    #include <vector>
    #include <iterator>
    
    using namespace std;
  
    vector<int> &split(const string &s, char delim, vector<int> &elems) {
        stringstream ss(s);
        string item;
        while (getline(ss, item, delim)) {
            if (item.length() > 0) {
                elems.push_back(stoi(item));  
            }
        }
        return elems;
    }
    
    vector<int> split(const string &s, char delim) {
        vector<int> elems;
        split(s, delim, elems);
        return elems;
    }
    
    
    vector<int> negative(vector<int> elems){
        vector<int> results;
       for (auto &elem : elems){
           int temp = 255 - elem > 0 ? 255 - elem : 0 ;
           results.push_back(temp);
       }
        return results;
    }
    
    vector<int> negativeAssembly(vector<int> elems){
        vector<int> results;
        for (auto elem : elems){
            asm (
                "sub  $255, %[in1];"
                "neg %[out]"
                : [out] "=r" (elem)
                : [in1] "r" (elem)
            );
            results.push_back(elem);
        }
        return results;
    }
    
    int main(){
        vector<int> elems;
        ifstream infile("./image.txt");
        for( string line; getline(infile, line ); ){
            elems = split(line, ' ');
            elems = negativeAssembly(elems);
        }
        

return 0;
}
```

image.txt file contains:

```
0   1   5   8   12
6   250 50  40  35
80  45  34  18  87
123 13  165 250 80
```

Now I write ***Negative*** function that for each pixel count it's subtraction from 255.

Then I write the subtraction part with inline assembly in ***negativeAssembly*** function. but I need to convert the all operation in function to assembly with **MMX or SSE** registers.
how can I do that, I'm really confused.

Comment: You're looking for `__m128i v = _mm_loadu_si128((const __m128i*)&elems[i])` and `_mm_subtract_epi32(_mm_set1_epi32(0xff), v)`.  You don't need inline assembly for this, and writing it in plain C should let a compiler auto-vectorize if you avoid `std::vector` push inside the loop (which might need to reallocate).

Comment: If your input numbers actually are only integers between 0 and 255, you should store them as `unsigned char` (or `uint8_t`) and you can use bitwise not (`~elem`) or xor with `255`. If you want to change elements in-place. just pass the `vector` by reference. And yes, avoid inline assembly for simple operations which the compiler is likely better at optimizing (unless you do it for educational purposes.)

Comment: @PeterCordes I used your code as below,   


`for (int64_t elem : elems)
    {
        __m128i v = _mm_loadu_si128((const __m128i*)&elems);
        __m128i pa = _mm_add_epi64(_mm_set1_epi16(0xff), v);
        results.push_back(elem);
    }`


but I couldn't use it, I don't know how to use the result.